# Is it possible to search by microdata/structured data in a standard Google search?

Tags: google-search, microdata, google-custom-search, structured-data

I have been using a Google Custom Search Engine to return useful results using standard X-Ray techniques and the more:pagemap:: techniques as outlined here
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search

Does anyone know how, on a standard google search, I could apply the same idea to query the Structured Data on a page when x-ray searching a site where the format of the structured data is known.

The Structured Data can be easily seen when testing the site url on this page
https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

How do I filter by this...?

Unfortunately more:pagemap and any other variations that I could think using the testing tool as a starting point didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Google Search* doesn’t support it.

You can’t directly search for metadata or structured data values, no matter how they are specified (RDFa, Microdata, JSON-LD, `meta`/`link`, Microformats, `rel` etc.).